# ROT128 byte-transformation encoding

Tags: python, python-3.x, formatting, bitwise

I'd like some feedback on code I wrote to obfuscate text on-disk. The basic idea is the same as [ROT13](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ROT13) (which is [implemented](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/3.8/Lib/encodings/rot_13.py) in the [Python standard library](https://docs.python.org/3/library/codecs.html#text-transforms)), except instead of rotating the English alphabet by 13, the underlying byte representation is rotated by 128. The use case is to hide data from a string-search.

Because this is such a general transformation, I decided that the user should specify a "base" codec, and then the code would register a version that performs ROT128 (*e.g.* specifying `'utf_8'` creates `'utf_8_rot128'`).

`rot128.py`

````py
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
'''
Provides codecs that perform a ROT128 transformation on their underlying
byte representation.
This module is side-effect free; to register codecs, use e.g.
    register_codecs(UTF_8, ASCII) # for 'utf_8_rot128' and 'ascii_rot128'
    register_rot128_codec() # for the bytes-to-bytes 'rot128'
'''

from typing import Dict, Iterable, Optional as Opt
from collections import defaultdict
from collections.abc import MutableMapping
import codecs

### The ROT128 transformation
ROT128_TRANS = bytes(range(256)[128:]) + bytes(range(128))
def rot128_transform(input: bytes) -> bytes:
    '''Rotate bytes from `input` by 128'''
    try:
        return input.translate(ROT128_TRANS)
    except AttributeError:
        return bytes(input).translate(ROT128_TRANS)

### Registration function and convenience aliases
UTF_8 = ('utf_8', 'U8', 'UTF', 'utf8') # in Python 3.8, add 'cp65001'
ASCII = ('ascii', '646', 'us-ascii')
def register_codecs(*encodings: Iterable[str]) -> None:
    '''Create and register codecs (with aliases) that perform ROT128 on
    their underlying byte representations. Arguments are iterables of aliases
    to the original encoding, e.g.
    ```
        register_rot128_codecs(('utf_8', 'U8', 'UTF', 'utf8'))
    ```
    creates the codec `utf_8_rot128`, with aliases
    ```
        u8_rot128, utf_rot128, utf8_rot128
    ```
    fetchable via `codecs.lookup(...)`
    '''
    # register the search function only once
    global _REGISTER_ONCE
    if _REGISTER_ONCE:
        codecs.register(_REGISTERED_CODECS)
        _REGISTER_ONCE = False
    # add codecs
    for encoding in encodings:
        # check that aliases refer to the same codec
        info_orig = codecs.lookup(encoding[0])
        if any(info_orig != codecs.lookup(alias) for alias in encoding[1:]):
            msg = f'{encoding!r} are not all aliases for the same codec!'
            raise ValueError(msg)
        # have we built this codec before?
        if info_orig in _REGISTERED_ALIASES:
            # fetch codec info
            for name in _REGISTERED_ALIASES[info_orig]:
                break
            info_rot128 = _REGISTERED_CODECS[name + '_rot128']
        else:
            # build codec, fetch info
            info_rot128 = _build_codec(info_orig)
        # register codec
        unregistered = set(encoding) - _REGISTERED_ALIASES[info_orig]
        for name in unregistered:
            _REGISTERED_CODECS[name + '_rot128'] = info_rot128
        # register aliases
        _REGISTERED_ALIASES[info_orig] |= unregistered

def _build_codec(codec_info: codecs.CodecInfo) -> codecs.CodecInfo:
    '''Create a ROT128'd codec based on `codec_info`'''
    
    def encode(input, errors: str = 'strict') -> bytes:
        input, inlen = codec_info.encode(input, errors)
        return rot128_transform(input), inlen
    
    def decode(input: bytes, errors: str ='strict'):
        return codec_info.decode(rot128_transform(input), errors)
    
    class Codec(codecs.Codec):
        def encode(self, input: str, errors: str = 'strict') -> bytes:
            return encode(input, errors)
        
        def decode(self, input: bytes, errors: str ='strict') -> bytes:
            return decode(input, errors)
    
    class IncrementalEncoder(codec_info.incrementalencoder):
        def encode(self, input, final: bool = False):
            return rot128_transform(super().encode(input, final))
    
    class IncrementalDecoder(codec_info.incrementaldecoder):
        def decode(self, input, final: bool = False):
            return super().decode(rot128_transform(input), final)
    
    class StreamWriter(Codec, codec_info.streamwriter):
        pass
    
    class StreamReader(Codec, codec_info.streamreader):
        pass
    
    return codecs.CodecInfo(
        name = codec_info.name + '_rot128',
        encode = encode,
        decode = decode,
        incrementalencoder = IncrementalEncoder,
        incrementaldecoder = IncrementalDecoder,
        streamwriter = StreamWriter,
        streamreader = StreamReader
    )

### Maintain registration with `codecs` module
class _RegisteredCodecs(MutableMapping):
    '''`dict`-like class that maps ROT128 codec names to their `CodecInfo`s'''
    
    def __init__(self) -> None:
        self._store: Dict[str, codecs.CodecInfo] = {}
    
    @staticmethod
    def _trans(key: str) -> str:
        '''Normalize codec name'''
        return key.lower().replace('-', '_')
    
    def __call__(self, key: str) -> Opt[codecs.CodecInfo]:
        '''Provide the search function interface to `codecs.register`'''
        return self.get(key, None)
    
    def __getitem__(self, key: str) -> codecs.CodecInfo:
        return self._store[self._trans(key)]
    
    def __setitem__(self, key: str, value: codecs.CodecInfo) -> None:
        self._store[self._trans(key)] = value
    
    def __delitem__(self, key: str) -> None:
        del self._store[self._trans(key)]
    
    def __contains__(self, key: str) -> bool:
        return self._trans(key) in self._store
    
    def __iter__(self):
        return iter(self._store)
    
    def __len__(self) -> int:
        return len(self._store)
    
    def __str__(self) -> str:
        return str(list(self.keys()))

_REGISTERED_CODECS = _RegisteredCodecs()
_REGISTERED_ALIASES = defaultdict(set)
_REGISTER_ONCE = True

### ROT128 bytes-to-bytes codec
def register_rot128_codec() -> None:
    '''Registers the 'rot128' bytes-to-bytes codec'''
    global _REGISTER_ROT128_ONCE
    if _REGISTER_ROT128_ONCE:
        codecs.register(_rot128_search_function)
        _REGISTER_ROT128_ONCE = False

def rot128_transcode(input: bytes, errors='strict') -> bytes:
    '''A `codecs`-module-style ROT128 encode/decode method'''
    return rot128_transform(input), len(input)

class Rot128Codec(codecs.Codec):
    '''ROT128 bytes-to-bytes codec'''
    def encode(self, input: bytes, errors: str = 'strict') -> bytes:
        return rot128_transcode(input, errors)
    
    decode = encode

class Rot128IncrementalEncoder(codecs.IncrementalEncoder):
    '''ROT128 bytes-to-bytes incremental encoder'''
    def encode(self, input: bytes, final: bool = False) -> bytes:
        return rot128_transform(input)

class Rot128IncrementalDecoder(codecs.IncrementalDecoder):
    '''ROT128 bytes-to-bytes incremental decoder'''
    def decode(self, input: bytes, final: bool = False) -> bytes:
        return rot128_transform(input)

class Rot128StreamWriter(Rot128Codec, codecs.StreamWriter):
    '''ROT128 bytes-to-bytes stream writer'''
    # need to specify (undocumented) charbuffertype for bytes-to-bytes;
    # see https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/3.8/Lib/encodings/base64_codec.py
    charbuffertype = bytes

class Rot128StreamReader(Rot128Codec, codecs.StreamReader):
    '''ROT128 bytes-to-bytes stream reader'''
    charbuffertype = bytes

_ROT128_CODEC_INFO = codecs.CodecInfo(
    name = 'rot128',
    encode = rot128_transcode,
    decode = rot128_transcode,
    incrementalencoder = Rot128IncrementalEncoder,
    incrementaldecoder = Rot128IncrementalDecoder,
    streamwriter = Rot128StreamWriter,
    streamreader = Rot128StreamReader
)

def _rot128_search_function(encoding: str) -> Opt[codecs.CodecInfo]:
    if encoding.lower() == 'rot128':
        return _ROT128_CODEC_INFO
    else:
        return None

_REGISTER_ROT128_ONCE = True
````

And a simple example:

```py
import codecs
import rot128
rot128.register_rot128_codec()
rot128.register_codecs(rot128.UTF_8)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    # seamless encoding
    write_text = 'Hello world! \n'
    with open('test.txt', 'w', encoding='utf_8_rot128') as f:
        f.write(write_text)
    
    # seamless decoding
    with open('test.txt', 'r', encoding='utf_8_rot128') as f:
        read_text = f.read()
        assert read_text == write_text
    
    # bytes-to-bytes is a little meaner
    with codecs.open('test.txt', 'rb', encoding='rot128') as f:
        read_bytes = f.read()
        # codecs.open doesn't have universal newlines
        read_text = codecs.decode(read_bytes, 'utf_8').replace('\r\n', '\n')
        assert read_text == write_text

    with open('test.txt', 'rb') as f:
        read_bytes = codecs.decode(f.read(), 'rot128')
        read_text = codecs.decode(read_bytes, 'utf_8').replace('\r\n', '\n')
        assert read_text == write_text
    
    # bytes-like object
    mybytes = write_text.encode('utf_8')
    memview = memoryview(mybytes)
    assert codecs.encode(memview, 'rot128') == codecs.encode(mybytes, 'rot128')
```

There's a few ugly things I'd like to draw attention to, namely

- `_RegisteredCodecs` is a reimplementation of `dict` to look up codecs (which is a lot of boilerplate). It does the same "normalization" as the `codecs` module, namely, lowercasing names and converting hyphens to underscores, and its `__call__` method implements the [search function](https://docs.python.org/3/library/codecs.html#codecs.register) interface to the `codecs` registry.
- [`bytes`-like object](https://docs.python.org/3/glossary.html#term-bytes-like-object) edge cases: the ROT128 transformation is implemented with [`translate`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#bytes.translate), but this does not exist for *e.g.* a `memoryview`, so it converts to `bytes` in that case; I'm not sure I should attempt to return the original class
- The logic in `register_codecs` is pretty involved, to prevent the user from shooting themself in the foot if they try to register invalid aliases or re-register existing aliases

As an outsider, I'm happy to accept style review as well.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

- Re-implementing a dict is completely unnecessary. `codecs.register()` expects a search *function*, so a plain function will work just fine. You can use a regular dict to store codecs (in a closure). Normalization can be implemented in its own function.

  Something as simple as this should work:

  ```py
  def register_codecs(*encodings: Iterable[str]) -> None:
      registered_codecs = {}

      def search(codecs_name):
          return registered_codecs.get(_normalize(codecs_name), None)

      codecs.register(search)

      # Add codecs

  def _normalize(encoding: str) -> str:
      return encoding.lower().replace('-', '_')
  ```

  Instead of storing codecs in the global variable `_REGISTERED_CODECS`, we just register another search function each time the user calls `register_codecs()` (which means `_REGISTER_ONCE` is also not needed any more; we just got rid of two global variables with one shot!)
- Now for the error checking in `register_codecs()`. Checking that aliases refer to the same codec is fine, but I doubt if it's really necessary to check for duplicates. The code works all right even if the same codec is registered twice. So I think it's probably not worth it.

  After removing the check for duplicates, the complete `register_codecs()` function now looks like this:

  ```py
  def register_codecs(*encodings: Iterable[str]) -> None:
      registered_codecs = {}

      def search(codecs_name):
          return registered_codecs.get(codecs_name, None)

      codecs.register(search)

      # then add codecs to registered_codecs
      for encoding in encodings:
          # check that aliases refer to the same codec
          info_orig = codecs.lookup(encoding[0])
          if any(info_orig != codecs.lookup(alias) for alias in encoding[1:]):
              msg = f"{encoding!r} are not all aliases for the same codec!"
              raise ValueError(msg)

          for name in encoding:
              registered_codecs[_normalize(name) + "_rot128"] = _build_codec(info_orig)
  ```

  And that's also one less global variable!
- `rot128_transform()` takes any bytes-like object as argument and returns bytes. It's OK to return bytes even if the caller passes in something else like a `memoryview`—the same way python's `Iterable` interface works.
- As a side note, the `range()` function takes two arguments: `start` and `end`. So instead of `range(256)[128:]`, try `range(128, 256)`.

Comment: Hey, thanks for the review! Give me some time to try this out and then I'll mark it as "Accepted" :D

Comment: Fun fact: according to [the `typing` docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/typing.html#typing.ByteString), `bytes` can be used as shorthand for a bytes-like object

Comment: " Normalization is also not needed, since the standard library normalize the names for you before calling your search function." This is untrue, not only does the library not normalize these names before sending them to the search function, but since the codec names ALSO come from the user, they need to be normalized.

Comment: Yeah, you're right. I thought the standard library does normalization because the `codecs.register()` docs says "Search functions are expected to take one argument, being the encoding name in all lower case letters". But it turns out that it only converts upper case letters to lower case and nothing else.